# Help with the squeeze theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, probability-limit-theorems

Is anyone able to help me/point me in the right direction with this question?

> Use the squeezing theorem to find the limit of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $n$-th term $a_n=\dfrac{\cos(n)}{n!}$.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Justify  these inequalities and find the limit of $(a_n)$:
$$0\le|a_n|\le \frac1n$$